# Orchestration on AWS without AWS Step Functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-lambda, amazon-eks, aws-step-functions

We are implementing a system where we have few Java components running on Spark cluster on AWS EKS. We need to orchestrates this components in a pipeline fashion where a file arrives on S3 and that needs to kick off a job on Component A and then depending on the outcome job on Component B and then C etc. Also, depending on the file type, we may want to skip certain 'steps' (job on a Component). The way we would kick off the job on individual components is by invoking `spark-submit` command via `kubectl`.

Step function seems to be an ideal candidate for this but we are not allowed to use this. Is there any better alternative to implement this whether using AWS native or something else?

Comment: There's Apache Airflow: https://aws.amazon.com/managed-workflows-for-apache-airflow/ or, since you are using Kubernetes you could look at workflow engines for Kubernetes like https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/

Comment: I’m curious to know why you are not allowed to use Step Functions?